# pydev disappeared when sudo eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, pydev, sudo, gksudo

pydev disappeared when sudo eclipse

I am trying to run py script with root power within eclipse.

So I started eclipse as 'sudo eclipse'. But then pydev plugin dispeared. The CDT plugin seemed to be OK.

I installed eclipse from Ubuntu repository and pydev using eclipse 's installation manager under my user account. Pydev is working fine when I start eclipse under my user account.

my platform: Ubuntu 9.10; Eclipse 3.5; Pydev 1.5

Thanks for any help

=====================================

Some follow-up: I manually downloaded and copied pydev to the '/usr/share/eclipse/dropins'. It seemed to be working

Answer (score 3):

Your plugin location may not be set for the root user.  Make sure the plugin path is included in the root user's eclipse environment.  Could the plugin be installed for only your user account?

These are just guesses - it's been a while since I've used Eclipse, and even longer since I've used it on Linux.

Comment: Thanks. How do I configure the Eclipse plug-in path? or I have to install the pydev plug-in as root? The CDT plug-in seems to be working fine though.

Comment: Easiest way would be to install it as root...or you could figure out where it installed itself and do it manually.  

CDT probably puts itself in the default plugin location, and it doesn't sound like pydev does.

Answer (score 0):

Never run graphical commands with sudo, use gksudo instead.
See [graphicalsudo](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo).

Comment: In this case it sounds like gksudo is exactly what he doesn't want. gksudo switches the environment to root's environment which probably won't contain his configuration.